# How to change the style of the cross reference in cleveref package?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I want to change the style of the crossed reference (chapter, section, figure, equation, ...) generated by using `cleveref` package, for example, put parentheses around the referenced item and use boldface for the numbers.

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extreport}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=1.50cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,citecolor=red, linkcolor=blue}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First  Chapter}\label{ch:chapter 1}
\section{Section One}\label{sec:section one}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section Two}\label{sec:section two}
\begin{align}
r =& \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\label{eq:equation 1}\\[2ex]
z =& \sqrt[3]{1 - 2r^2}\label{eq:equation 2}
\end{align}
see \cref{sec:section one} in \cref{ch:chapter 1}\\
\Cref{eq:equation 1} is the governing equations, \cref{eq:equation 2} is the second equation.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Should just the number of the item being cross-referenced be typeset in bold, or should the surrounding parentheses be typeset in bold as well? Please advise.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I think `\bfseries` has no effect. I compiled with and without it and I saw no difference in the format.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: I see bold reference 'numbers', I could have placed the parentheses inside as well, to make them bold too, but that doesn't look nice, in my point of view

Comment: @ChristianHupfer can you spot the difference here http://imgur.com/a/uuY1W ? it is very subtle, if existed.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: Sorry, I had a different version: I meant: `\crefdefaultlabelformat{({#2\bfseries#1#3})}`, I used the other comment above from memory, not by copy and paste. `#2 ` and `#3` belong to `hyperref` parts and disable the `\bfseries` then.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer it has no effect for me, maybe it is my glasses fault :)

Comment: To the OP: Unrelated: Please don't use spaces in label names, even if it's allowed...

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: See the difference between `\cref` (after label format change) and the normal `\ref` here: http://imgur.com/a/ptgH9

Comment: @ChristianHupfer that's we are talking about :) but it is weird that `cref` almost gives me the nearly same bold face with/without loading bfseries commands. Anyway, maybe I need to sleep more a little bit :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the numbers *and* the surrounding parentheses should be typeset in bold, add the instructions

```
\crefdefaultlabelformat{#2\bfseries\upshape(#1)#3}          
\creflabelformat{equation}{#2\bfseries\upshape(#1)#3}
```

after loading `cleveref`.

If only the numbers but not the surrounding parentheses should be typeset in bold, issue the instructions

```
\crefdefaultlabelformat{#2(\textbf{\textup{#1}})#3}
\creflabelformat{equation}{#2(\textbf{\textup{#1}})#3}
```

Observe the use of `\upshape`/`\textup` to make sure that the number (and, if required, the parentheses) are always typeset in the upright font shape.

A full MWE (minimum working example) that renders both the numbers and the surrounding parentheses in bold:

[image]

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extreport}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,graphicx,xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref}  
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefdefaultlabelformat{#2\bfseries\upshape(#1)#3}
\creflabelformat{equation}{#2\bfseries\upshape(#1)#3}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First  Chapter}\label{ch:chapter 1}
\section{Section One}\label{sec:section one}
\section{Section Two}\label{sec:section two}
\begin{align}
r =& \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\label{eq:equation 1}\\[2ex]
z =& \sqrt[3]{1 - 2r^2}\label{eq:equation 2}
\end{align}

See \cref{sec:section one} in \cref{ch:chapter 1}.

\Cref{eq:equation 1} is the governing equation, and  \cref{eq:equation 2} is the second equation.
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up comment: Use the instructions

```
\crefdefaultlabelformat{(#2\textbf{\textup{#1}}#3)}
\creflabelformat{equation}{(#2\textbf{\textup{#1}}#3)}
```

if only the cross-referenced numbers, but not the surrounding parentheses, should be rendered in bold and be made into hyperlink targets (and hence be rendered in blue, given the `hyperref` settings in force).

Comment: Perhaps you should add a normal `\ref{ch:chapter 1}` next to a `\cref{...}`  to show the difference (especially the font change) ...

Comment: @DiaaAbidou - The screenshot you've produced uses a sans-serif font (which one??) that's not used in the OP's example. What does the screenshot look like if the default fonts are used?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou - If you copied and pasted the OP's code into ShareLaTeX, why would you expect to get the results from *my* code? I certainly wouldn't...

Comment: @Mico, I copied his main code while changing the format by your bold commands.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou - Your ShareLaTeX setup appears to be somewhat non-standard. I have no idea which font family you use; it may be the case that the particular sans-serif font that you use cannot produce **bold** material. At any rate, the screenshot *I* have  posted demonstrates that my code does render the cross-referenced numbers in bold.

Comment: thanks for the answers, I want the parentheses be blacked and just the number be bold and colored?

Comment: and the same thing in the equation number.

Comment: @Mico - This is my last question about this post, is it possible to change the color and font style of one of the cross reference (e.g. chapters) and the remaining cross reference do not affect by this manipulating?

Answer (score 5):

For the parentheses, put this in preamble `\crefdefaultlabelformat{#2(#1)#3}` where `#1` stands for the cited item as stated in cleveref [documentation](http://download.nus.edu.sg/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf)

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extreport}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=1.50cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,citecolor=red, linkcolor=blue}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefdefaultlabelformat{#2(#1)#3}


\begin{document}
\chapter{First  Chapter}\label{ch:chapter 1}
\section{Section One}\label{sec:section one}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section Two}\label{sec:section two}
\begin{align}
r =& \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\label{eq:equation 1}\\[2ex]
z =& \sqrt[3]{1 - 2r^2}\label{eq:equation 2}
\end{align}
see \cref{sec:section one} in \cref{ch:chapter 1}\\
\Cref{eq:equation 1} is the governing equations, \cref{eq:equation 2} is the second equation.
\end{document}
```

[image]